# delete from table where rownum() = 3

Tags: database, hsqldb

How to delete third row from any table using "rownum" (i'm using hsqldb)
i try many query and the result return always = 0 
for example this one ->

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER FROM

(SELECT ROWNUM() AS ROW_NUMBER, abs.* FROM absence abs)

WHERE ROW_NUMBER = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the third row in a subquery in the DELETE statement.

For example

```
DELETE FROM customer WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM customer ORDER BY id OFFSET 2 FETCH 1 ROW ONLY)
```